# Angular Forms not passing data from HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-forms

I seem to have a problem passing input data from HTML's `<select>` element to Angular Forms itself.

Here's my code first.

**Filename: home-page.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="addPaste(rForm.value)">

    ...

    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select formControlName="pasteSyntax">
            <option *ngFor="let choices of pasteSyntaxChoices" [value]="choices.value">{{ choices.text }}</option>
        </select>
        <label>Syntax Highlighting</label>
    </div>

    ...

</form>
```

**Filename: home-page.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home-page',
    templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.css']
})

export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

    rForm: FormGroup;
    paste: any;

    ...

    pasteSyntax: string = '';

    ...

    pasteSyntaxChoices = [
        { value: "plain", text: "Plain Text" },
        { value: "html", text: "HTML" },
        { value: "css", text: "CSS" },
        { value: "js", text: "JavaScript" },
        { value: "php", text: "PHP" },
        { value: "perl", text: "Perl" },
        { value: "go", text: "Go (Golang)" }
    ];

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.rForm = fb.group({

            ...

            'pasteSyntax': [null, Validators.required]

            ...

        });
    }

    addPaste(paste) {

        ...

        this.pasteSyntax = paste.syntax;

        ...

        console.log(paste);
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

}
```

**Additional Info:**

```
@angular/animations: 4.2.4
@angular/common: 4.2.4
@angular/compiler: 4.2.4
@angular/core: 4.2.4
@angular/forms: 4.2.4
@angular/http: 4.2.4
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.4
@angular/router: 4.2.4
core-js: 2.4.1
rxjs: 5.4.2
zone.js: 0.8.14
```

**Expected Output (From `console.log`):**

```
Object
    pasteSyntax: "plain"
```

**Current Output (From `console.log`):**

```
Object
    pasteSyntax: null
```

Can anyone tell me where did I go wrong or did I use the wrong syntax?

Comment: What is `paste.syntax`? Is this really supposed to be `paste.pasteSyntax`? From what I can see, you do not have a field named *syntax* in the form group.

Comment: @R.Richards, nope. Everything in my actual code works fine so that isn't the problem.

Comment: Try adding `#rForm` inside the form tag. I think that what you are passing to `addPaste` isn't quite right (obviously, it is null).

Comment: @R.Richards, that actually crashed my whole form lol. See: [Console Log](https://imgur.com/kqiPxm4)

Comment: That was not my intention! :) I was hoping that would get you the reference you needed.

Comment: @R.Richards, actually, my original source code has `<input>` tags in it. And, they work great so the only problem or obstacle I'm trying to get over is `<select>`. Not sure why is it behaving this way though ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @R.Richards declaring a variable is not required if you are referencing it through `[formGroup]="rForm" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is this line in your `addPaste`:

```
this.pasteSyntax = paste.syntax;
```

it should be:

```
this.pasteSyntax = paste.pasteSyntax;
```

But as mentioned by Nilandri, you don't need to variable, you can access the value from the form in your template with, or then print the `pasteSyntax` property when you submit your form with `rForm.value` as parameter:

```
addPaste(value) {
  console.log(value.pasteSyntax);
  console.log(this.rForm.get('pasteSyntax').value);
  // or
  console.log(this.rForm.controls.pasteSyntax.value)
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdgxrn?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I do believe that it is the same thing as `console.log(paste)` though more specific. Tested your answer, still returned `null` from the console. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well I just like to use the variables available, instead of having 'unnecessary' variables, but of course you can use it :) The answer I provided should work just fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcavs7?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @EtosticityRammington updated answer, noticed the error when looking closer, but as said, the answer I provided before editing should work tho :)

Comment: Actually, your demo works! Code compared with my side and yours, are totally the same. But I just can't work out why isn't it working. Is it possible to communicate somewhere else for this? Thanks! :D

Comment: Really hard to say what could be the issue :D If you have more code than presented in your question, create a demo by inserting more of your code little by little. Who knows, there could be something else affecting this?

Comment: I'll just give you my whole source code for investigation. [Source Code](https://drop.me/M5YrWj) Thanks for the help, anyway! :D

Comment: I'll take a look a bit later, going offline for a while :) I'll let you know after I looked at it.

Comment: @EtosticityRammington I was a bit stumped at first, until.... I have never used Materialize, but it seems that it is causing your issue. If you remove the styling from the two materialize css files your app works as it should when you click the pure html dropdown. You have to look into that, if you find some help to overcome this.

Comment: Ah... Hmm alright, thanks for the help anyway, appreciate it! :D